# Using constexpr in a type dependent context

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Easy question, is this legal?

```
template<class T>
struct foo {

using type = std::conditional<IF_CONDITION<T>::value, constexpr int, int>::type;

};
```

Compiler error: "error: "constexpr" is not valid here"
Haven't been able to find any documentation on this. Because its a compile time condition it seems like this should be able to do in theory at least.

Comment: `constexpr int` is not a type

Comment: "const int" would be a type. "constexpr int" is not a type.

Comment: I see, I thought it was comparable to `const` Do you know if their is any way to emulate this? (Other than class specialization)

Comment: @JosephFranciscus In what kind of code would you need something to be conditionally constexpr? Maybe we could help you with that.

Comment: I'm writing a library like `Eigen` 
So an object will be like `Vector<class T, int Rows>`
if `Rows == 0` than I want a dynamic Row value (IE regular `int`) 
else I want it to be `constexpr` (as it will be known at compile time)

Comment: I can just use specialization so its not too big of a deal though, this may just be easier to write than a specialization.

Comment: @JosephFranciscus Specialization is the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard:

> The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a
>   variable or variable template or the
>       declaration of a function or function template. A function or static data member declared with the constexpr
>       specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable (10.1.6). If any declaration of a function or function
>       template has a constexpr specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the constexpr specifier. [ Note:
>       An explicit specialization can differ from the template declaration with respect to the constexpr specifier.
>       — end note ] [ Note: Function parameters cannot be declared constexpr. — end note ]

So constexpr is not supposed to be within the template parameter.

In your case you could create the type specialization alias with:

```
template<typename T>
using MyVec0 = Vector<T,0>;
```